# C; Inline assembly syntax mistake "Expected string literal before numerical constant"

Tags: c, inline-assembly

When I compile the following example code (these are essentially junk assembly statements with no real purpose) I get the following error;

> def-asm-pop.c:13:3: error: expected string literal before numeric
>   constant

Line 13 is the uncommented "ASM" line;

```
#define iMOV "mov %eax,%ebx\n\t"
#define iNOP "nop\n\t"
#define iASM __asm__(iMOV iNOP)

#define MOV 0xB8
#define NOP 0x90
#define ASM __asm__(MOV NOP)

int main() {

  //iASM;    /* This one works when uncommented */

  ASM;       /* The one causes the error when uncommented */

  return 0;

}
```

There maybe an error in my *Hello World* style attempt at inline assembly, but that is another stepping stone for me to overcome. At this point in time it seems I can't define a list of opcodes and then define an assembly statement list built from them, in the same way I can by defining the text commands. How can I make `ASM` work like the `iASM` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message states, the `__asm__` operator wants a string and not a number, and in that string it wants valid assembler.

You are trying to directly write binary opcodes, this has not much to do with assembler.

Comment: Well now that you say it like that, it seems pretty obvious! Hah, what a dummy I was. Thanks Jens Gustedt, I will rethink what I am doing and try Eric's suggestion below.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
#define MOV ".byte 0xB8\n"
#define NOP ".byte 0x90\n"
```

The exact syntax is of course dependent on your assembler (and the appropriate machine language is dependent on your target platform). This is not much use for anything other than experimenting; it is not a good way to write code.

Comment: I agree it isn't a good way to write, yes it is purely for experimental work, just my own self learning etc. I'll give your suggestion a try.